# How to execute .sh with certain file which has .xyz extension

Tags: bash, shell

I have `abc.sh` file and input source (`input.xyz`).

I always execute the `abc.sh` file with input sourece
(e.g. I type `sh abc.sh input.xyz`)
However, as the number of directory increases I cannot bother to type input file name.

How do I implant the process into the abc.sh file to execute instead of typing the command (`sh abc.sh input.xyz`)?

The current script is this

```
INPUT=$1                            

n="1"                               
numb=$(sed -n "$n"p $1)             
#echo $numb
dummy="NULL"
```

Thank you for the comment it's my mistake.
when I run the script I type

```
sh abc.sh 000.xyz
```

everytime when I run `000.xyz` will be in different number so `.xyz` is only fixed.

Comment: Is the input file always `input.xyz`? If not, how do you determine the input file?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want your modified script to always behave as if you had typed `sh abc.sh input.xyz` (or `abc.sh input.xyz`) with your current script (and never e.g. `abc.sh input2.xyz`)? Or do you want your script to process all files of a certain name pattern? Please [edit] your question to add clarification.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.  Try describing what you do manually, without a script.  Without really understanding what you're asking, I can guess and say that you're trying to do input redirection ( ./script.sh < inputfile ).  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake  @Bodo

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake @Liczyrzepa

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use bash to loop through all your possible input files (e.g. 001.xyz, 002.xyz, etc.) in a directory. It may be easier to put it into a separate BASH script to organize what you are running (e.g. batch_run.sh).

For example, you can use a `for` loop to go through every xyz file in the current directory and run your `abc.sh` script on it:

```
for input_file in *.xyz
do
    sh abc.sh $input_file
done
```

You mentioned that you may have multiple directories. You can expand the wildcard (*) to account for directories too (relative to your current position):

```
for input_file in */*.xyz
do
    sh abc.sh $input_file
done
```

If your script has to be run in the same directory as the input file, you can also do various actions (e.g. `cd`) within the loop, such as something like this:

```
# remember the original directory before the for loop
original_directory = $(pwd)

# loop through all valid directories containing xyz files
for input_file in */*.xyz
do
    # enter the directory of containing the xyz file
    cd $(dirname $input_file)

    # run the script on the xyz file
    sh abc.sh $(basename $input_file)

    # return to the original directory
    cd ${original_directory}
done
```

It can get more or less complex depending on what you want to do and your specifications, however I hope this will give you an idea of how BASH `for` loops can allow you to automatically repeat commands.

Comment: I used first method which works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I would like to use the third method which you mentioned at last. However, I have hundreds of directories which named in number 001 002 003... in that case how to make a script? (I literally started to learn bash from today....)